# SQL sub query displaying a grouped value of one column based on the maximum average value in another

Tags: sql, db2

Im trying to compute the maximum average of safety_score based on community_area_name. I can do this by the query:

```
SELECT  max(average_safty) as maximum from (select community_area_name, AVG(safety_score) as average_safty from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS group by community_area_name) ;
```

But now i want to display the community_area_name for the result. I have tried:

```
SELECT  max(average_safty) as maximum, community_area_name from(select community_area_name, AVG(safety_score) as average_safty from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS group by community_area_name) ;
```

But then i get an error because it needs to be grouped. And when i group like this:

```
%sql SELECT  max(average_safty) as maximum, community_area_name from (select community_area_name, AVG(safety_score) as average_safty from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS group by community_area_name) group by community_area_name ;
```

the result is a list of all the averages per community_area_name, not only the maximum average.

How do i get a result like below?:

|**community_area_name | maximum**|

Name of area  |       highest average  |

Answer (score 1):

Use `order by` and `fetch` clauses:

```
select community_area_name, avg(safety_score) as average_safety
from CHICAGO_PUBLIC_SCHOOLS
group by community_area_name
order by average_safety desc
fetch first 1 row only;
```

Comment: Hi, thanx for your input. I was actually trying to find find out if it was possible to get a single result without limiting the rows. But of course your suggestion is a practical solution. Thanx!